# multiple command prompt command on single line

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I created a batch file with 2 commands on a single line but I can't get it work.

What I'm trying to do is that create a subdirectory and copy test.pdf to DIR3 with new filename hello world.pdf.

Any thoughts guys? how about if the directory already exist?

```
mkdir W:\DIR1\DIR2\DIR3  && copy "W:\test\test.pdf" W:\DIR1\DIR2\DIR3\hello world.pdf
```

Comment: What's `-p` for? And check your quotation!

Comment: why there's a double quote right after copy command?

Comment: @aschipfl - it should not produce an error ,but will create two directories and one of them will be `-p`

Comment: @npocmaka, I know, but the OP does not most probably...

Comment: So - what is your code doing that it shouldn't be doing, or not doing that it should be? Only you can tell us what's in your mind - we have to make assumptions, which is not good.

Comment: i thought when using -p it will not throw an error if the already directory exist?

Comment: Note: `&&` is [conditional](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html). If `mkdir` fails, because the folder already exists, the next command would not be executed. You probably want a single `&` instead.

Comment: One likely problem is that there's no double-quotes around the one file that contains a space in it: `W:\DIR1\DIR2\DIR3\hello world.pdf`

Comment: Why use the conditional operator?   Just use one ampersand.  If it already exists it will just throw an error and then move the file to the directory.  You can suppress the error by directing standard error to the nul device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the syntax:

```
command1 && command2
```

Tested this for `dir && echo foo` and it works.

So your command becomes :

`mkdir -p "W:\DIR1\DIR2\DIR3" && copy "W:\test\test.pdf" W:\DIR1\DIR2\DIR3\hello world.pdf`

Maybe you could have used Google?

Oh and there was an extra `"` after `copy` in your command.

Comment: "_Maybe you could have used Google?_" Maybe you could have used Google or `mkdir /?` to find out that there's no `-p` option.